# TCP freeze problems

Tags: freeze, tcp

I have a server which I am testing for functionality (not load, not stress) with tsung. 50 users / second, 100 total users. Judging from tsung (tsung is the testing framework) graphs, there TCP connections (red line) drops to 0 while the commenced user sessions (green line) does not. 
Server logs show nothing to be gripping onto, so I am speculating some kind of TCP issue. 
I did check with netstat and the TCP sessions were established on both tsung machine and server machine, yet, there nothing gets exchanged through them... and of course, the graph below shows some kind of problem. What could I be facing here, how to solve it ?

[image]

```
> root@XMPP:~# cat /etc/lsb-release  
> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10 
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Thank you

just got another set of results - it seems nothing changes over 20k seconds:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How come I have not thought of the obvious... packets (application level packets) were getting oer the top of server queues so they were dropped. Hence the situation at hand.

LE. F**k this! got it to no longer drop packets, same effin results :|